# Conducting a search with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

I have a search program which grabs books by ISBN which I have stored in a list from Amazon and puts them in a list. My question is, how can I get this solution to work using a concurrent approach such as threading? I believe I know how to create threads already, it's just accomplishing the task of the book search simultaneously that's causing the confusion.

```
for number in isbn:
    response = amazon.ItemSearch(Keywords="%s" %number, SearchIndex="Books", ResponseGroup="Large")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "xml")
    title = soup.Title.get_text()
    asin = soup.ASIN.get_text()
    rank = int(soup.SalesRank.get_text())
    book_list.append(Book(title, asin, rank))
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Comment: If you are trying to hit amazon's website with multiple threads they may not appreciate that.

Comment: How else can I perform parallel searches? I'm sure amazon wont mind if its for educational purposes... right?

Comment: Anytime you are scripting against a webservice you want to be mindful of how many queries you are generating. I don't know what Amazon's terms of service are but some places will block an IP if they are getting 1000s of searches per second.

Comment: What version of python are you using? I would use asyncio if I had access to python 3, otherwise there is the threading module.  Let me know and I can put a small example together.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I was approaching the problem wrong. There was no need to hit Amazon with multiple threads, I just had to add them to the book list using threads.